# FileProvider failed to find configured root that contains... error

Tags: java, android

I have seen this question asked previously, but before you mark this question as redundant let me just say that I've been trying to figure this out for three hours and I'm just confused.  My goal is to take a photo, set it to an imageview, and upload it to Firebase Storage.  In order to get the full size photo, I believe I have to save it to a local file, because the FileProvider takes a reference to a file and that's where the full size photo goes.  Is that correct so far?  I cannot for the life of me get the FileProvider to accomplish this.

After many attempts, this is what I have:

```
// It all starts here
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("DebugMySocks", "Change photo button clicked");
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                    getPackageName(),
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp;
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mProfileImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}

// in manifest file
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>

// in /xml/filepaths.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="com.example.kevin.moresocksplease/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

and the error message is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.kevin.moresocksplease/files/Pictures/JPEG_20171214_111337.jpg706457555.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
<external-path name="my_images" path="com.example.kevin.moresocksplease/files/Pictures" />
```

with:

```
<external-files-path name="my_images" />
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick.  I knew it couldn't be something big but it was even smaller than I expected.